# Regex to match individual non-whitespace characters not contained in a word

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to match individual non-whitespace characters not contained in a specific word. The closest I've got is the following.

```
(?!word_to_discard)\b\S+\b
```

The problem is that the above expression matches the words that are not word_to_discard, but not the individual non-whitespace characters. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Could you please provide some example input / output

Comment: `\b(?!\S*[abcde]\S*)\S+\b` would match any word not containing any of the letters from a to e, but I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the problem:

1) You need to match characters not contained in a specific word. The easiest way to do that is to use a character group `[ ]` with negation `^`. Let's also exclude any space character by adding `\s` token in the character group.

```
[^word_to_discard\s]
```

2) Now, you're saying only individual characters need to be matched, so you can use a boundary token `\b` to ensure there are no preceding/next alphanumeric characters.

```
\b[^word_to_discard\s]\b
```

3) In order to match all individual characters, you'll need to iterate through all matches. That thing is language/engine specific. For example, in JavaScript you'll need to specify `/g` parameter at the end of regex pattern, so each subsequent `rgx.exec(text)` invocation will get the next match in the *text*:

```
const text = "w y o r d z";
const rgx = /\b[^word_to_discard\s]\b/g;

rgx.exec(text); // Matches "y"
rgx.exec(text); // Matches "z"
rgx.exec(text); // returns null (no more matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex `\b\S+\b` matches between 2 word boundaries one or more times not a whitespace so that would not give your the individual non white-space characters.

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match what you don't want, like `word_to_discard` and then capture in a group what you do want to match. You could for example use a character class to match lower characters a, b or c [`[a-c]`](https://regex101.com/r/x7W7pg/1) not contained in word_to_discard or use `\S` to match not a whitespace character.

`word_to_discard|(\S)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzJspC/1)